# Convert list of tuples and list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

> I have a list of tuples

```
data = [(2015-10-08,2016-07-17,2015-09-09,2014-01-29),(Alex, Jerry, Tony, Tom), (5,6,7,8)]
```

> And I have a list, this list contains column headings.
> title = [Date , Name, Age]
> With this list and list of tuples I want a dictionary.
> This is the expected output

```
output = {1:{'Date': 2015-10-08,2016-07-17,2015-09-09,2014-01-29} ,{'Name' : Alex, Jerry, Tony, Tom}, {'Age' : 5,6,7,8}}
```

Comment: Should the output be: `output = {'Date':(2015-10-08,2016-07-17,2015-09-09,2014-01-29) ,'Name' : (Alex, Jerry, Tony, Tom), 'Age' : (5,6,7,8)}`, where value is tuple?

Comment: No sir! Actually I need dictionary of dictionaries as mentioned above

Comment: The internal dictionary then should have a key value pair, which doesn't seem so in your case..from you output, it looks like internal nested dict can be a tuple or a list

Comment: Sorry for that! Now the question has been edited. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict(zip(title, data))
```

Or for making them sets:

```
dict(zip(title, map(set, data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
output = {}
output["Date"] = set(data[0])
output["Name"] = set(data[1])
output["Age"] = set(data[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [('2015-10-08','2016-07-17,2015-09-09','2014-01-29'),('Alex', 'Jerry', 'Tony', 'Tom'), (5,6,7,8)]
title = ['Date', 'Name', 'Age']

your_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(title, data)}
```

Comment: This works, of course, but the `dict` constructor already takes the output of `zip` as is... Nonetheless, I like having this answer here, since I think it makes it clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the solutions:

```
data = [('2015-10-08','2016-07-17','2015-09-09','2014-01-29'),('Alex', 'Jerry', 'Tony', 'Tom'), ('5','6','7','8')]
title = ['Date', 'Name', 'Age']
output = {}
for i in range(len(title)):
    output[i+1] = {title[i]: ",".join(data[index])}
    
print (output)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'Date': '2015-10-08,2016-07-17,2015-09-09,2014-01-29'}, 2: {'Name': '2015-10-08,2016-07-17,2015-09-09,2014-01-29'}, 3: {'Age': '2015-10-08,2016-07-17,2015-09-09,2014-01-29'}}
```